# ¿Cómo accedo a un array multidimensional con clases y objetos? PHP

Tags: php, array, clase, objeto

¡Buenas!

El caso es que voy un poco perdido con php

Tengo este constructor el cual crea un array multidimensional usando los atributos de una clase.

```
 function __construct()
{
    $this->productList = array(
        new Producte(1, "LlapisR", 2.3, "Llapis vermell", 50),
        new Producte(2, "LlapisG", 2.3, "Llapis verd", 80),
        new Producte(3, "LlapisB", 2.3, "Llapis blau", 10),
        new Producte(4, "Grapes", 2.7, "Caixa de grapes", 50),
        new Producte(5, "folis100", 2.5, "Paquet 100 folis", 60),
        new Producte(6, "folis500", 1.3, "Paquet 500 folis", 40),
        new Producte(7, "clips100", 4.0, "Paquet 100 clips", 24),
        new Producte(8, "clips200", 7.5, "Paquet 200 clips", 0),
        new Producte(9, "Tisores", 9.5, "Tisores per tallar paper", 2)
    );
}
```

El problema es que tengo me cuesta muchísimo saber como acceder a cada atributo usando el for each.

Debo hacer un método *productExists($id)*, és decir, pasándole un id tengo que buscar si está en la lista y hacer return de *true* o *false*.

Tambíen tengo otro, que necesito la misma rutina para poder hacerlo, *getProduct($id)* , al cual le paso el id y hago *return* del objeto con el id.

No necesito la solución en si, si no saber como hacerlo para poder aprender.

Ante todo, muchas gracias a las personas que ayudáis a los demás en este ¿foro?

Edito:
¡Gracias al usuario Triby por las sugerencias!

La clase Producte

```
<?php
class Producte
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $price;
    protected $description;
    protected $property;

    public function __construct($id, $name, $price, $description, $property)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->property = $property;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
    public function getProperty()
    {
        return $this->property;
    }
}
```

Clase ProducteQ

```
<?php
//productQ is the daughter class of "Product"
include_once "producte.php";
class ProducteQ extends Producte
{

    public $stock;

    function __construct($id, $name, $price, $description, $property, $stock)
    {
        parent::__construct($id, $name, $price, $description, $property);
        $this->stock = $stock;
    }

    //function to check the stock, if the quantity inserted is bigger than the stock, the function returns false
    function checkStock($quantity)
    {
        if ($quantity > $this->stock) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Clase Select

```
<?php
class Select
{

    private String $name; // variable String per desar el nom d'un camp de tipus select
    private $values; //Array amb les diferents opcions de la llista select.

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getValues()
    {
        return $this->values;
    }

    public function setValues($values)
    {
        $this->values = $values;
    }

    public function makeSelect()
    {
       echo '<select name="' . $this->name . '"><option value="No response" default="default">-- Select one -- </option>';
        foreach ($this->values as $value) {
            echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
```

Este fichero es adicional, pero también tengo que saber como acceder al array porque tengo que hacer una tabla HTML con toda la lista.

```
<?php

include_once "magatzem.php";


$magatzem = new Magatzem();
```

El resultado que obtengo si ejecuto  `var_dump($this->productList);` al final del constructor:

`array(9) { [0]=> object(Producte)#2 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(1) ["name":protected]=> string(7) "LlapisR" ["price":protected]=> float(2.3) ["description":protected]=> string(14) "Llapis vermell" ["property":protected]=> int(50) } [1]=> object(Producte)#3 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(2) ["name":protected]=> string(7) "LlapisG" ["price":protected]=> float(2.3) ["description":protected]=> string(11) "Llapis verd" ["property":protected]=> int(80) } [2]=> object(Producte)#4 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(3) ["name":protected]=> string(7) "LlapisB" ["price":protected]=> float(2.3) ["description":protected]=> string(11) "Llapis blau" ["property":protected]=> int(10) } [3]=> object(Producte)#5 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(4) ["name":protected]=> string(6) "Grapes" ["price":protected]=> float(2.7) ["description":protected]=> string(15) "Caixa de grapes" ["property":protected]=> int(50) } [4]=> object(Producte)#6 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(5) ["name":protected]=> string(8) "folis100" ["price":protected]=> float(2.5) ["description":protected]=> string(16) "Paquet 100 folis" ["property":protected]=> int(60) } [5]=> object(Producte)#7 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(6) ["name":protected]=> string(8) "folis500" ["price":protected]=> float(1.3) ["description":protected]=> string(16) "Paquet 500 folis" ["property":protected]=> int(40) } [6]=> object(Producte)#8 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(7) ["name":protected]=> string(8) "clips100" ["price":protected]=> float(4) ["description":protected]=> string(16) "Paquet 100 clips" ["property":protected]=> int(24) } [7]=> object(Producte)#9 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(8) ["name":protected]=> string(8) "clips200" ["price":protected]=> float(7.5) ["description":protected]=> string(16) "Paquet 200 clips" ["property":protected]=> int(0) } [8]=> object(Producte)#10 (5) { ["id":protected]=> int(9) ["name":protected]=> string(7) "Tisores" ["price":protected]=> float(9.5) ["description":protected]=> string(24) "Tisores per tallar paper" ["property":protected]=> int(2) } }`

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar algunas aclaraciones: 1. ¿Qué devuelve `new Producte()` y cómo se accede a cada propiedad?, 2. ¿Qué obtienes si al final del constructor agregas `var_dump($this->productList);`?

Comment: Hecho! Gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->productList` es un arreglo de objetos donde todas las propiedades están protegidas. Comenzando con el método `productExists($id)`:

```
public function productExists($id) {
    // Recorrer lista de productos
    foreach($this->productList as $product) {
        // $product es instancia de producte, comparar id
        if($product->getid() == $id) {
            // El producto existe, devolver verdadero
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Terminó el ciclo, no se encontró el producto
    return false;
}
```

Obtener producto por ID es más o menos lo mismo, solo que si se encuentra el producto vas a devolver un objeto, de lo contrario, devuelves falso:

```
public function getProduct($id) {
    // Recorrer lista de productos
    foreach($this->productList as $product) {
        // $product es instancia de producte, comparar id
        if($product->getid() == $id) {
            // El producto existe, devolver objeto
            return $product;
        }
    }
    // Terminó el ciclo, no se encontró el producto
    return false;
}
```

De acuerdo a la forma en que definiste el arreglo original, para trabajar con el siguiente producto:

```
(4, "Grapes", 2.7, "Caixa de grapes", 50)
```

Después de instanciar la clase y asumiendo que `productList` es de acceso público:

```
$magatzem = new Magatzem();

// Ejemplo 1: Verificar que existe el producto
if($magatzem->productExist(4)) {
    // El producto existe
}

// Ejemplo 2: Obtener producto como objeto
$producto = $magatzem->getProduct(4);
// Solo si no es falso
if($producto !== false) {
    // Se obtuvo correctamente el producto
    // Puedes acceder a propiedades usando los métodos correspondientes
    echo "Nombre: {$producto->getName()}";
}

// Ejemplo 3: Recorrer la lista
foreach($magatzem->productList as $product) {
    // Aquí puedes crear cada fila de la tabla
    // Obteniendo propiedades del objeto como en el ejemplo 2
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me ha servido muchísimo de verdad, ya no solo para solucionar este ejemplo sino porque iba bastante perdido.